# For vs While for finding last item in linked list

Tags: c++, c++11, for-loop, while-loop

Should I use for or while loop for finding last item in linked list?

```
Item * last = list;
for (; last->next; last = last->next) ;
```

versus

```
Item * last = list;
while (last->next)
{
    last = last->next;
}
```

it's 2 lines versus 5 and it seems almost equally readable. Why I always see only the while form?

Comment: The `for` loop usually suggests that the loop variable is a private, local detail of the loop. If the point of the loop is to change some *other*, external variable, then the `while` version is a bit clearer in that regard. In particular, if the increment part of the for loop changes external state, that may be hard to see and confusing.

Comment: I believe both are equal wrt memory and time.

Comment: It's pretty much a personal preference..

Comment: Also, btw, there shouldn't be a `;` after the for loop - I think you have made a typo.  Or is it intentional?

Comment: @BatCoder: And that's why you shouldn't use the for loop. It takes too much time confusing the reader.

Comment: The while loop could also be 2 lines. It is your choice to make it 5.

Comment: @BatCoder I see a `;` after the for loop.

Comment: @gsamaras, yes.  That is what I want to know - is it intentional or a typo.

Comment: Sorry, I misread your comment @BatCoder. Of course it is intentional and it denotes an empty body. Without it it will be implied that the next line of code will be the body of the [tag:for-loop].

Comment: @juanchopanza it's companies policy to structure the code like this. the `{` and `}` must always be on line alone.

Comment: Right, but you're presenting the number of lines as a "difference" between the two, and it isn't. You could also write the `for` version in 5 lines.

Comment: @juanchopanza true didnt look at it like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're going to compare line counts, at least try to do it reasonably accurately. The `for` loop should be formatted more like this:

```
Item * last = list;
for (; last->next; last = last->next) 
    ;
```

This makes it much more apparent that the `for` loop is (intentionally) controlling an empty statement. The `while` loop can be written more like this:

```
Item * last = list;
while (last->next)
    last = last->next;
```

If we insist that we need braces around even a single controlled statement, they still end up with the same line count for each:

```
Item * last = list;
for (; last->next; last = last->next) {
    ;
}
```

vs:

```
Item * last = list;
while (last->next) {
    last = last->next;
}
```

So, the difference in line count was due solely to the formatting you chose to use (and, particularly, the fact that you didn't use the same or even similar formatting for the two).

Others have already pointed out that these are likely to compile to identical code, and I agree that you can (and should) expect this to be true with any reasonable compiler.

That leaves style and readability as the sole differentiation. In this respect, the `for` loop is clearly preferable. A few people who've apparently never recovered from early exposure to BASIC (or possibly FORTRAN) insist that `for` loops should be used only for simple counted loops like those supported in BASIC and FORTRAN. Applying this limitation to C or C++ is simply wrong-headed and silly. C's `for` loop was made much more versatile for a good reason, and placing purely artificial limits on it does nobody any favors at all.

Simple rule of thumb: if you're actually using at least two out of the three clauses in the `for` loop's header, it's better to use a `for` loop than a `while` loop. A `for` loop with an empty body is roughly similar to a constructor with an empty body: it may be unfamiliar and confusing to people who don't know the language, but to anybody who actually knows the language, it's trivial and as familiar as the fingers on their hand.

Answer (score 5):

> Why I always see only the while form?

There are two reasons why the `while` form is preferred:

- **Loops with empty bodies are not as readable as loops that have at least one statement in their body** - Programmers new to C find the semicolon after the `for` loop confusing, or even miss the semicolon altogether, not understanding what is going on. There is no such confusion about the `while` loop.
- **`for` loops with loop variable declared outside the loop provide a strong indication that you actually want a `while` loop** - Loop variables are scoped to the body of the loop. When you declare them outside the loop, it is because you want the ending value of the loop variable among the results of your loop.

Comment: I dunno about that second point. If your loop has a `continue`, you may still need the iteration guarantee that the `for` provides.

Answer (score 4):

The two loops are logically equivalent, and, most likely, will end up getting compiled to identical code.

Use whichever one you like.

Answer (score 1):

Because the [for-loop](/questions/tagged/for-loop) is used when you know how many steps you are going to make. Moreover, this loop can have its variables private (the iterator).

The [while-loop](/questions/tagged/while-loop) is used until a condition is meet. You can simulate all loops with this loop.

However, as one can easily see, both can be used, since they are equivalent.